# BGR - RGB Pixel layout problem. How to fix wrong subpixel optimization in "LCD font smoothing"

Tags: macos, display, hardware, font, video-adapter

Maybe someone has idea how to solve this problem. I have display Dell P2314H it has BGR subpixel layout instead of common RGB. If to turn on font smoothing on Mac - fonts are looking terrible. I have tried to edit ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver..plist, trying to modify PixelEncoding property from from `--------RRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB` to `--------BBBBBBBBGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRR`and also some other combinations. Rebooted after several modifications without any success.

On Ubuntu there is dconf-editor, where you can modify `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings`and set `rgba-order` property to `bgr`

But is there any chance to fix wrong subpixel layout setting on Mac OS? This problem manifests itself both on Hackintosh and if to connect external Display to MacBook.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a matter of getting a macOS driver from the vendor for that display? There might be a great answer on how to hack this and I'll +1 it when someone reports a workaround. Just curious if you made headway on this in the years since asking.

Answer (score 4):

The way to "fix wrong subpixel layout setting on Mac OS" is using System Preferences, Display, Rotation 180 degrees (from Standard). This makes an external LED display switch from BGR to RGB pixel orientation.

However you also complain your fonts look terrible. Under System Preferences, General, uncheck Use LCD font smoothing when available. Now ALL fonts will look identical in EVERY orientation. If you do not believe me, then make your whole monitor display white and rotate 90, 180, 270. Do the colors change? No. Because if you disable font smoothing then every font is made from WHOLE pixels.

So without font smoothing if your fonts still look terrible, then your problem has to do with something else and NOT BGR or RGB pixel orientation.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't going to like it but turn it upside down.. Then you will get RGB

Comment: Did you even think about the answer
Believe it or not, the answer is tried and is correct.
Flipping it upside down will transform BGR to RGB and OSX handles that perfectly 
And I know what I am talking about because I had been researching this topic for more then a month and I finally gave up on a BGR monitor exactly for that reason.
For extra read

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19541142