# Do monitors with BGR subpixel layout still render fonts worse than monitors with RGB subpixel layout on MacOS, without subpixel antialiasing?

Tags: macos, display, hardware, font, resolution

I get somewhat conflicting information on this topic. On one hand there are answers like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171141/bgr-rgb-pixel-layout-problem-how-to-fix-wrong-subpixel-optimization-in-lcd-f) claiming that BGR layout is no longer an issue without subpixel antialiasing, which has been removed in newer versions of MacOS. On the other hand there are people who say that BGR screens can still ruin the experience as long as you're not gaming/watching videos etc. And apparently on Windows at least, even if you can use ClearType to mitigate the problem with native apps, a lot of apps (e.g. Google Chrome) [don't support BGR well](https://www.rtings.com/monitor/tests/picture-quality/text-clarity).

I'm interested in the monitor Aorus FV43U, but since I'm going to program on it for the majority of time, I'm not sure if it would be a wise choice. Is it true that while Windows still struggles with BGR, I would not have any issues with MacOS?